# How to set paging sorting filtering and editing in asp grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to apply sorting ,paging searching and editing in asp gridview.
already apply the paging,sorting and searching with bootstrap datatable library.
i want to apply editing also,already applied with gridview_editing.but paging is not work with editing

protected void dgvSearch_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (dgvSearch.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

            if ((gv.ShowHeader == true && gv.Rows.Count > 0)
                || (gv.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty == true))
            {

                dgvSearch.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks to "false" as follows-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false">
    </asp:GridView>
```